# What is the most efficient way to match a polygon to a value?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, d3.js

This is a general d3 question. Let's say you have a large geometryCollection, say all the counties in the U.S. That's over 3,000 polygons. Matching them against a 2 column, 3000+ row dataset takes a long time (n^2) when running a set of nested loops, ie.,:

```
//loops through 3000+ polygons
polygonCollection.map((polygon) => {
  //checks against the full dataset every time from start
  for (let j = dataset.length - 1; j>-1; j--) {             
    if (dataset[j].matchTest === polygon.properties.ID) {
      // a match occurred
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

What are some known ways to make this more efficient?

One idea I have is to order the polygons alphabetically or from smallest to largest `id` value. Then to modify the search for the "Match" in a set of binary trees that look higher or lower in the dataset depending on where the sought match lies.

Comment: binary search and index sort is your friend ...

Comment: Could you clarify? I assume you mean: Given a sorted index, binary search is the most efficient way. I ended up using this implementation btw.

Comment: Yes you just add one index array for each property you want to search for. The array size is the same as number of polygons. And it contains index of polygon sorted by your feature. Inserting new polygon into this is slow operation as you need inserting into sorted array but the search itself is just  binary search on index sorted array. I use this for example for point tables so I can have just distinct points stored (no duplicates) to preserve space and speed up geometry operations ...